# How can I enable backspace key in VI?

Tags: freebsd, vi, backspace

I have bare-bone FreeBSD installation. No package installed. And VI doesn't accept backspace key. (I pressed backspace key but nothing happen)
How can I enable backspace key in VI?

Oh, and I'm using Mac, and controlling FreeBSD on VM or via Terminal.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't accept backspace"? Do you see something like `^H`, nothing at all or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this in the terminal before running vi:

```
$ stty erase [Ctrl-V] [Backspace]
```

where [Ctrl-V] is pressing Control + V and [Backspace] is pressing the backspace key.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me - in Terminal Preferences - select  Advanced tab - check the "Delete sends Ctrl-H"

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Super User. Your answer would be far more useful to the asker as well as future visitors if it explained *why and how* this solves the asker’s issue. SU is meant to be a community Q&A site, which works best when answers are canonical for the issue at hand (you might want to read the [answer] guidelines).

Answer (score 0):

From `:h backspace-delete`:

> Backspace and Delete keys                               `*backspace-delete*`
>
> ---
>
> In 3.0 both the delete key and the backspace key worked as a backspace in
>   insert mode; they deleted the character to the left of the cursor.  In 4.0 the
>   delete key has a new function: it deletes the character under the cursor, just
>   like it does on the command-line.  If the cursor is after the end of the line
>   and 'bs' is set, two lines are joined.                  `|<Del>| |i_<Del>|`
>
> In 3.0 the backspace key was always defined as CTRL-H and delete as CTRL-?.
>   In 4.0 the code for the backspace and delete key is obtained from termcap or
>   termlib, and adjusted for the "stty erase" value on Unix.  This helps people
>   who define the erase character according to the keyboard they are working on.
>                                                           `|<BS>| |i_<BS>|`
>
> If you prefer backspace and delete in Insert mode to have the old behavior,
>   put this line in your vimrc:

```
    inoremap ^? ^H
```

> And you may also want to add these, to fix the values for `<BS>` and `<Del>`:

```
    set t_kb=^H
    set t_kD=^?
```

> (Enter ^H with CTRL-V CTRL-H and ^? with CTRL-V CTRL-? or `<Del>`.)
>
> If the value for t_kb is correct, but the t_kD value is not, use the ":fixdel"
>   command.  It will set t_kD according to the value of t_kb.  This is useful if
>   you are using several different terminals.              `|:fixdel|`
>
> When ^H is not recognized as `<BS>` or `<Del>`, it is used like a backspace.

Comment: This is for VIM - not VI.  The two are very different in their command sets.

Comment: (This question comes up in the Google search results for the "backspace not working" problem in `vim`.) The instructions in this answer didn't work for me. However, placing `set backspace=2` in the vim config did the trick.